# Discord Ban All Command for Server Rebuilder

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

**Hi! I am trying to make a server rebuilder bot in JS.
I don't know how to make a ban all command for rebuilding the server.
Can you help me?**

**The code I used:**

```
client.guilds.forEach(guild => {
        guild.members.forEach(m => {
            m.ban();
        });
    });
```

Comment: This is considered API abuse and will get your account terminated, as if Discord themselves ran this script but ban() bans your account. ;)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [@Logan Devine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14133230), the following script is considered API abuse as it mass bans users from a server without reason. You may want to update this command to provide a warning and maybe restrict its usage from anyone.

However, per version 12 of Discord.js, caching was introduced. Your code is receiving an error because it can't ban a non-cached member. Additionally, you are using the `forEach` function which isn't supported by a Collection. Use the `each` function instead.

```js
guild.members.cache.each(m => {
  m.ban();
});
```